# Querying top element with different year attributes in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem in which I need to list out all products having maximum profit for every different year.

The table looks like:

[image: this]

**Sample queries to copy**:

```
   name    | year | profit 
-----------+------+--------
Printer   | 2010 |  14000
Monitor   | 2011 |  13500
Mouse     | 2011 |   5600
Printer   | 2011 |  14000
Key Board | 2011 |   7500
Pen Drive | 2010 |    900
Pen Drive | 2011 |   4350
Key Board | 2010 |   3000
```

I need to insert query such that it prints product with maximum profit in a year with its name and profit.

For eg: In this table, it would be

```
Printer | 2010 | 14000
Printer | 2011 | 14000
```

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I just added output as an image, not the code.

Comment: And how do I copy and paste the sample data from the image so I can run a query to see if my potential answer works correctly?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are getting it wrong buddy, That image contains an output which is never needed to be copied, It's just for elaborating my question.

Comment: Sorry, I just added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DISTINCT ON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) for this:

```
select distinct on (year) *
from profit
order by year, profit desc;
```

Comment: This one is short, sweet and saved my day, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`select a.name, a.year, b.maxprofit
from (select max(profit) as maxprofit, year
group by year) b
join
profit a
on b.maxprofit = a.profit`

Comment: Actually I need this: 
```
select DISTINCT a.name, a.year, b.maxprofilt
from (select max(profit) as maxprofilt, year
from profit group by year) b
join
profit a
on b.maxprofilt = a.profit;

```

Thanks for help